# Can the asymptotic expression $\mathcal{O(log(n) \cdot log(m))}$ be simplified?

Tags: asymptotics

I constructed an algorithm $A$ with input $(n,m)$ and I found that it has runtime 
$\mathcal{O(log(n) \cdot log(m))}$. I was asking myself if this expression can be simplified somehow, but I could not find a way. Do you see a possiblity here?

Comment: What *could* be simpler? You use the two input values $n,m$ once each, you apply a simple standard function to each, you combine the two by the simple operation of multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is
$$\mathcal O(\log(n^{\log m})) $$
But this is silly and not really any simpler. Go with what you have.